# use exec(); in a php script to send email from shell

Tags: php, bash, email

I am trying to make a php script that uses the `exec()` function to run a command that sends an email.

I am looking at something like this:

```
<?php
$sendTo = 'RECEPIENT';
$subject = "SUBJECT";
$message = "MESSAGE";

exec('/bin/mail -s "$sendTo" "$sendTo" < $message');
?>
```

I am not sure however if the variables I have declared in php can be used in the exec() function. The command however also does not seem to be correct.

Comment: any reason you don't use php's built in mail functions?

Comment: Yes, I have issues with the mail(), it executes for almost 1 minute and that could not be resolved so far.

Comment: well generally speaking php's mail function does the exact same thing that you are trying to do (depending upon how it is configured, it is probably piping to sendmail). So if it is having issues, running mail from the CLI , probably be the same.  Also it is normally easier to use popen, to get a pipe to the mail or sendmail program and then just echo or print the contents of the message into it, since unless $message  is a file. your can't shell redirect

Comment: Why not use http://swiftmailer.org?

Answer (score 1):

When enclosing strings in single-quotes (`'`), the variables are not expanded.
You can try something like this:

```
exec('/bin/mail -s "' . $sendTo . '" "' . $sendTo . '" < ' . $message);
```

Take a look at the **[PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single)** for more details.

Comment: `escapeshellarg()` should do it too.

Comment: I don't really see how `escapeshellarg()` good be useful here. Could you give an example ?

Comment: It'd escape the `'` in the variables too for example.

Comment: I get the following when using the exec() that you suggested:          sh: MESSAGE: No such file or directory

Comment: @Jason Carter: Have you tried executing the command directly (i.e. from the shell, without PHP) ? It could be a problem with your command itself and not the way you issue it from within PHP.

Comment: @bwoebi: Since the variables' values will be enclosed in `""`, I don't think it is necessary to escape `'` inside the variables' values.

Comment: @ExpertSystem Oh, I misread, but you need to escape the `"` then ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The `<` is a shell redirect, and is expecting a filename  .

you can do something like this, (although I think there are other issues causing mail to be slow)

```
<?php
   $mail_command = "/bin/mail -s \"$subject\" $sendTo";
   $fd = popen($mail_command, 'w');
   fputs($fd,$message);
   pclose($fd);
?>
```