# how to send mail by use of shell_exec command in php

Tags: php, linux

I am using following code for send mail but it through msg "Null message body; hope that's ok " and mail is not send

```
$body='sdfsdf';
$subject='sdfsdf';
$to='test@gmail.com';

echo $output = shell_exec("echo $body && mail -s \"$subject\" $to");
print_r ("$output"); 
die;
```

Comment: Why not just use the built-in php mail function?

Comment: i have to use it by shell_exec

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you are using `&&`?  I think it should be `shell_exec("echo \"$body\" | mail -s \"$subject\" $to");`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [use exec(); in a php script to send email from shell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16700135/use-exec-in-a-php-script-to-send-email-from-shell)

Comment: both case it doesn't work :(

Comment: I just did a test with what I commented and it worked fine